# interplay between vs. among vs. of -- best option?

Tags: american-english, academia

In an academic paper, I would like to say that "I explore the interplay "between/among/of" (A) the representation of love in The Great Gatsby and (1) modern conceptions of love, (2) Biblical conceptions of love, and (3) Greek conceptions of love."

So, I explore A+1, A+2, A+3. Do I use between, among or of?

If I explored A+1+2+3, would the word choice be different?

Comment: For the 3 pairs, *between*. For the set of 4, *among* - but "A" should be given a number so that it looks like part of the list.

Comment: I vote for *of* or *between*, but do you really mean *interplay?*  This suggests a reciprocal relationship such that modern conceptions of love influenced the representation of love in *The Great Gatsby* (and vice versa) and that Biblical conceptions of love influenced Greek conceptions of love.  Did the Greeks read the Bible? (Obviously Greeks living after a certain point read the Bible; maybe those are the Greeks we're talking about)